# Is it possible to sort an almost sorted array in parallel?

Tags: arrays, language-agnostic

An "almost sorted array" is defined here as each element being at most `k` positions away from their position in a sorted array. The array size is `n`. The basic algorithm in serial is using a min heap (assuming you want to sort in ascending order), which gives O((n-k)log k + k) running time, or alternatively, you can use insertion sort and get O(nk) running time.

For either of these algorithms, I don't see a good way to parallelize it. You can, of cause, split the array up into contiguous chunks, and send each segment to a single thread, but the issue is there's always going to some elements at the ends of the segments that could fall into a different segment in the sorted array. So if you were to use multithreading, you would run into data race issues, or alternatively, you can add in locks to avoid the data race issues at the cost of performance.

Are there better ways to solve this problem in parallel?

Comment: If n is much bigger than k, it makes sense to split it into as many subarrays as you have processors and use the min heap algorithm running on all subarrays in parallel.  When you're done, you know that the only elements not in the correct locations are within k elements of the boundaries between the subarrays. Then finish up by re-sorting those areas, again in parallel.  It's just a 2-pass algorithm. No locking required. There's probably a more refined way to present this idea.

Comment: @Gene Would it be more correct to say that we'd want n/num_processors >> k, than simply n >> k? I suppose there could be a situation where n >>> k but you have a bunch of processors such that n/num_processors ~ k.

Comment: @Gene As for the second pass, you would use one less processor right? Since you just need to check the boundaries between consecutive processors.